Question in Linear Algebra regarding a Gram matrix
I will first provide the question:
Let V be an n dimensional inner product space. let v1,...,vn ∈ V and let (A)ij = (<vi,vj>).
prove: det(A) = 0 if and only if v1,...,vn are linearly dependent.
So the solution I found isn't very clear to me pretty much from the get go. they first look at a column j of A and show it according to definition (<v1,vj>...<vn,vj>). Afterwards they decide to choose a random aj (a being the scalar for the linear combination) and multiply the column by it to the left: (These will be column vectors but I will write them horizontally for comfort)
ΣajCj(A) = (Σaj<v1,vj> ... Σaj<vn,vj>) = (aj becomes the complex conjugate) (<v1,Σajvj> ... <vn, Σajvj>)
From here I just lose them completely. I assume they are trying to show A has a 0 column thus it doesn't have an inverse? They basically go on to assume Det(A) = 0 than continue with 2 directional statements until they reach vi being linearly dependent for the ith column.
sorry if I formatted anything wrong, this is my first time using this site!

Regarding formatting, please use mathjax to tyope the mathematical formulas. As it stands, your formulas are pretty much unreadable.

Let $B$ be the matrix whose columns are (the standard coordinate vectors of) $v_1,\dots,v_n$. Then $A=B^\top\bar B$. Thus, $\det A = \det B\det\bar B = |\!\det B|^2$. If $\det A=0$, then $\det B=0$, from which it is immediate that $\{v_j\}$ is linearly dependent.
